How do I get the MSAL Intercepter to add headers to the Apollo GraphQL requests
I'm trying to setup authentication in my app and I've tried a large variety of resources to resolve this.
Simply put, the MSAL interceptor doesn't seem to be working in the application. What do I need to do to get it right?
The login and logout process works fine however I get a 500 error when I run a query against the server, and there are no tokens in the request header. The host function just returns the current window's origin (rather than hard coding the host)
In my app.module I have the below.
/**
 * Here we pass the configuration parameters to create an MSAL instance.
 * For more info, visit: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/configuration.md
 */
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
}

/**
* Set your default interaction type for MSALGuard here. If you have any
* additional scopes you want the user to consent upon login, add them here as well.
*/
export function MsalGuardConfigurationFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: loginRequest
  };
}

/**
* MSAL Angular will automatically retrieve tokens for resources
* added to protectedResourceMap. For more info, visit:
* https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/initialization.md#get-tokens-for-web-api-calls
*/
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string | ProtectedResourceScopes> | null>();

  protectedResourceMap.set(protectedResources.graphMe.endpoint, protectedResources.graphMe.scopes);
  protectedResourceMap.set(protectedResources.graphContacts.endpoint, protectedResources.graphContacts.scopes);
  protectedResourceMap.set(host() + graphURI, [ {httpMethod: "POST", scopes: ["api://adtakr/Application.Run"]}]);

  return {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      protectedResourceMap,
      authRequest: (msalService, httpReq, originalAuthRequest) => {
          const resource = new URL(httpReq.url).hostname;
          let claim =
              msalService.instance.getActiveAccount()! &&
                  getClaimsFromStorage(
                      `cc.${msalConfig.auth.clientId}.${msalService.instance.getActiveAccount()?.idTokenClaims?.oid
                      }.${resource}`
                  )
                  ? window.atob(
                      getClaimsFromStorage(
                          `cc.${msalConfig.auth.clientId}.${msalService.instance.getActiveAccount()?.idTokenClaims?.oid
                          }.${resource}`
                      )
                  )
                  : undefined; // claims challenge e.g {"access_token":{"xms_cc":{"values":["cp1"]}}}
          return {
              ...originalAuthRequest,
              claims: claim,
          };
      },
  };
}
export function ApolloFactory(httpLink:HttpLink) {
      {
        const basic = setContext((operation, context) => ({
         
        }));
        const auth = setContext((operation, context) => {
          const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
       
          if (token === null) {
            return {};
          } else {
            return {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              },
            };
          }
        });
        
        const link = ApolloLink.from([basic, auth, httpLink.create({ uri: graphURI })]);
        return {
          cache: new InMemoryCache({addTypename: false}),
          
          link: link
          }
        };
      }
...

 providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_FLAGS,
      useValue: {
        useInitialLoading: true, // enable it here
      },
    },{
    provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
    useFactory: ApolloFactory ,
    deps: [HttpLink],
    
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MsalGuardConfigurationFactory,
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
    },
    MsalService,
    MsalBroadcastService,
    MsalGuard,
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]```


export function host() {
    return window.location.origin
}

Edit to add: So far as I can see in the browser debugger, the code for the interceptor config factory is never called. At least, when I add a breakpoint to the return statement in Firefox the breakpoint never fires.

I feel like a bit of an idiot now.
I was missing the following in the Providers.
{
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },

This tells angular to use the msal interceptor for intercepting http requests.
